# What sword does Lady Hoteshem have in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, world-of-warcraft-classic

I don't think I've seen this sword anywhere else. Is there a way to find out what it is, even if it isn't a weapon that is obtainable by players?

[image]

Comment: If it's not on WoWhead it most likely doesn't exist as named item. The database there includes unobtainable items as long as they have an ID.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an exact match - however for a very close alternative, you can look at:

Beheading Blade: https://classic.wowhead.com/item=15253/beheading-blade

[image]

or Battlefield Destroyer: https://classic.wowhead.com/item=8199/battlefield-destroyer

[image]